# Increase Space of /usr directory in Cent OS

Tags: centos

On my CentOS 5 server, `fdisk -l` outputs:

```
Disk /dev/xvda: 100.0 GB, 100000595968 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 12157 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1               1         487     3911796   83  Linux
/dev/xvda2             488         731     1959930   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/xvda3             732       12157    91779345   8e  Linux LVM
```

and `df -h` outputs:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            3.7G  1.4G  2.4G  37% /
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr  4.0G  4.0G   20K 100% /usr
/dev/mapper/vg00-var  4.0G  440M  3.6G  11% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-home 4.0G  269M  3.8G   7% /home
none                  512M  1.4M  511M   1% /tmp
tmpfs                 512M     0  512M   0% /usr/local/psa/handlers/before-local
tmpfs                 512M     0  512M   0% /usr/local/psa/handlers/before-queue
tmpfs                 512M     0  512M   0% /usr/local/psa/handlers/before-remote
tmpfs                 512M   16K  512M   1% /usr/local/psa/handlers/info
tmpfs                 512M     0  512M   0% /usr/local/psa/handlers/before-local
tmpfs                 512M     0  512M   0% /usr/local/psa/handlers/before-queue
tmpfs                 512M     0  512M   0% /usr/local/psa/handlers/before-remote
tmpfs                 512M   16K  512M   1% /usr/local/psa/handlers/info
tmpfs                 512M     0  512M   0% /usr/local/psa/handlers/spool
```

My `/usr` drive doesn't have any free space, but `fdisk` shows 100GB of unused space. Can I use that space to increase the capacity of the `/usr` directory? How? And how can I remove unwanted files from `/usr`?

Comment: fdisk is saying your disk is 100gb in size, not 100gb is free. Is this machine a virtual machine guest ? xvda tends to suggest it is. If so you can add anouther xen disk volume to the machine

Comment: on re-reading, i may have misunderstood "space" to imply "free space". -- what does `lvs` and `pvs` give ? you should be able to expand the /dev/mapper/vg00-usr logical volume if you have some space space with `lvextend`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you need to see if you have any available pe's in your volume group (in this case vg00). Check the output of

```
vgdisplay vg00
```

Then, assuming you have some PE (Physical Extent)s free, you can extend the /usr volume,

```
lvextend -L +<x-amount>G /dev/vg00/usr
```

after that you need to resize your filesystem to reflect the new size of this "partition":

```
resize2fs /dev/vg00/usr
```

assuming it is ext{3,4}.

If you have no PE's available, you could consider either to shrink another volume in the same group (like home in this case), or add another PV.
Regardless, note that the fact you have a partition that's 100GB in size does not mean you have access to 100GB. Since it is a physical volume used for LVM it only means you have 100GB worth of PE's.

Comment: Great answer :) However, you may need to use **resize4fs** instead of **resize2fs** if your partition filesystem is `ext4` (check in `/etc/fstab` file if necessary), otherwise you may get an error `Filesystem has unsupported feature(s) while trying to open x/y/z`, see http://systemadmin.es/2010/09/resize2fs-filesystem-has-unsupported-features-while-trying-to-open-devlocalhome

Comment: I had to use `xfs_growfs` instead of `resize2fs`, but this is a really helpful answer. Thank you.